# Deleting first node in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I know that this was answered many times, but I just can't figure out what is wrong.

I have a structure

```
typedef struct zaznam{
   char kategoria[53];
   char znacka[53];
   char predajca[103];
   double cena;
   int rok;
   char stav[203];
   struct zaznam *next;
   }ZAZNAM;
```

And I want to delete first node this way.

```
for(prev = act = prvy; act!=NULL; prev=act, act=act->next){
    if((strstr(act->znacka,vyber)!=NULL)){

    if(act->znacka==prvy->znacka){ 
    //if "znacka" of the actual node is equal to the first

        prev=prvy->next; //in "previous" is pointer to the second node
        free((void *)act); //free first node
        prvy=prev; //first node = previous 
    }
    else{ //this works
        prev->next=act->next;
        free((void *)act);
        act=prev;
    }
```

And it works for everything but not for the first node.

Comment: Isn't `act->znacka==prvy->znacka` comparing the pointers, thus equivalent to comparing the struct address itself? I.e. shouldn't you use `strcmp` or the like?

Comment: Well, it should compare two strings for example in `act->znacka` is word "one" and in `prvy->znacka` is "one" it will work. I tried it with `printf`, and it prints what it should print.

Comment: It doesn't work for e.g. `char x[2] ={'a,',0}; char y[2]={'a',0}; assert(x==y);`  It compares pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like when you delete the first node you're not properly assigning `prev` to point to the next node when you continue on the next iteration of the `for`-loop.  For instance, in your first `if` statement to check if you're at the first node, you do the following:

```
prev=prvy->next; //in "previous" is pointer to the second node
free((void *)act); //free first node
prvy=prev; //first node = previous
```

That does free the first node, but, immediately in your `for`-loop you then assign `act` to `prev` here:

```
for(prev = act = prvy; act!=NULL; prev=act, act=act->next)
```

Since freeing memory doesn't actually erase the contents of memory, you proceed down the rest of the list as if the first node had not been freed. Actually using a freed pointer like that is undefined behavior, so anything could happen (i.e. you could crash, etc. ... in this case it seems like you aren't).

Try changing your code to the following:

```
for(prev = act = prvy; act!=NULL;)
{
    if((strstr(act->znacka,vyber)!=NULL))
    {
        if(act==prvy)
        { 
            //we're at the first node
            ZAZNAM* temp=act->next; 
            free((void *)act); //free first node
            prev=act=prvy=temp; //re-establish starting condition
        }
        else
        {   
            prev->next=act->next;
            free((void *)act);
            act=prev->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //iterate here because if you delete the first node, you don't want
        //to start iterating like would happen if you kept iteration in the
        //for-loop declaration
        prev=act;
        act=act->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I used another variable called `pom`,(`*pom, pom=prvy->next`) and I used it instead of `prev` but it is still not working.
I also changed `if` to `if(strcmp(act->znacka, prvy->znacka) == 0)`
now it looks like this 
`pom=prvy->next`
`if (strcmp(act->znacka, prvy->znacka) == 0){
        
        free((void *)act);
        act=pom;
`

Comment: Jason: Yes it deletes everything it should delete. i tried it many times

Comment: Are you attempting to delete a single node or all the nodes in the list? It seems like it's all the nodes in the list ...

Comment: Yes all the nodes, actually its something like list of cars, and if I want to delete for example cars "Honda" and Hyundai i will just write part of it name for example "nda" and it will delete them

Comment: Sounds like you only want to delete select nodes, not all the nodes ... is that correct?

Comment: Sure, I delete just those I want to, not all. If I want I will delete 2 of 10. its ok. but if i try to delete first node in the list, it will stay there

Answer (score 1):

Well, you violate your own invariant `prev->next == act` already in the beginning: `for (prev = act = prvy;...`
Second, this `act->znacka==prvy->znacka` should be `act==prvy` to find out whether you are at the beginning of the chain, otherwise it confuses people.

And I would probably try to reestablish you starting (but wrong) invariant (which is `act==prev`) by adding `act=prev;` for the first case. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a loop. Deleting the first entry in a list is just a matter of

```
tmp = head->next
delete head
head = tmp
```